# Using SQL to perform a match and index function

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a new table (Table B), where i will input the value for column "S/N" and by default it will return the corresponding value from Table A when it matches with the value in S/N.

Table A

S/N  Content

1      A

2      B

3   C

4   D

Table B

S/N Content

2
1
3

I am new to SQL, appreciate if you can show the code on how to create table B please.

Comment: What do you mean `default it will match against Table A `, I am not sure what's your insert logic

Comment: I have amended my question, this should be clearer now.

Comment: read up on foreign keys and joins in SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.TableA')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TableA
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.TableB')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TableB

CREATE Table TableA ([S/NContent] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO  TableA
SELECT '1 A' UNION ALL
SELECT '2 B' UNION ALL
SELECT '3 C' UNION ALL
SELECT '4 D'

SELECT SUBSTRING([S/NContent],1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[S/NContent])) AS [S/NContent] INTO TableB
FROM TableA

SELECT * FROM TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Comment: I think u are mistaken, Table A contains two column (S/N and Content). I am trying to create Table B. For example when I input 3 in table B, it will return C for column Content for Table B.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question 
Are you asking about relations in SQL? If SN is primary key in A, reference SN column in B as primary key.

```
create table A (
    SN int primary key,
    Content varchar(10)
)

create table B (
    --dunno what the primary key will be
    SN int foreign key references A(SN),
    Content varchar(10)
)
```

Here's how to use it. You join two tables on foreign key

```
select *
from B 
join A on A.SN = B.SN
```